# PySpark and Kafka: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'File file... does not exist'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a simple Spark Structured Streaming app where I need to read a stream from Kafka. However, when I run the following code:

```
df = spark \
.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
.option("subscribe, "mytopic") \
.load()
```

Then I'm getting the following error:

```
AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".
```

So, according to the Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide, I need to run the following command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 ...
```

This gives me the following error which I do not understand:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'File file:/home/myname/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/... does not exist' Please specify one with --class.
```

Note: I am inside my `spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2` folder when executing this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> according to the Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide, I need to run the following command:

The `...` is not literal. You need to provide the rest of the command, which includes `--class`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: Thanks, specifying `pyspark-shell` instead of `...` solved the problem. Also, if you are using Jupyter, you could also do `import os` and `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = f'--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 pyspark-shell'` to make it work.